# Can gelatine digestion make blood more thick?

Tags: human-biology, hematology

Can gelatine cause blood thickening if digested?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, because gelatin is a mixture of collagen-derived peptides. When you eat them, they are first hydrolyzed by stomach acids into constituent amino acids. These amino acids are then absorbed from the small intestines as nutrients.